# Value of this must be of type EventTarget

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I'm on the latest version of **nextjs** with the **App Router**. I'm trying to get fetch the data from my next api on the `/api` endpoint but it returns an error 500.

> Error [ERR_INTERNAL_ASSERTION]: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_THIS]: Value of "this" must be of type EventTarget

This is the content of the next api file `app/api/route.ts`:

```js
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";

export const POST = async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
  console.log(req);

  return NextResponse.json({ data: "accessToken" });
};
```

and this is how I'm trying to call it in the server side:

```js
"use client";

import { useSearchParams } from "next/navigation";

export default function Home() {
  const authorizeTwitchApp = `${process.env.twitchApiUrl}/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=${process.env.twitchClientId}&redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000&scope=channel%3Amanage%3Apolls+channel%3Aread%3Apolls+openid`;

  const queryParam = useSearchParams().get("code");

  const getAccessToken = async (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const response = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ code: queryParam }),
    });

    const data = await response.json();

    console.log(data);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <a href={authorizeTwitchApp}>click me !!</a>
      <button onClick={(e) => getAccessToken(e)}>send code to api !!</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same mistake.
As I understood from the
documentation https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/route. Request is received in the form of a promise, after which you need to convert it to an object using the method .json()